# Spring Boot : How to access repository in java class @Autowired not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Spring Boot : How to access repository in java class @Autowired not working**

Please explain your solution with sample code as I am new to Spring Boot.

**Repository**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface StoreRepository extends CrudRepository<Store, Integer> {

    List<Store> findAll();
}
```

**Entity Store**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Store {

    @Id
    private Integer sid;
    private String sname;


    public Store() {

    }

    public Store(Integer sid, String sname) {
        super();
        this.sid = sid;
        this.sname = sname;

    }

///GETTER and Setters   here...

}
```

**Store Service **

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class StoreService {

    @Autowired
    private StoreRepository storeRepository;

    public StoreService() {

    }

    public List<Stores> getAllStores(){
        return (List<Stores>) storeRepository.findAll(); /* This works good. Through controller I can retrieve all data*/

    }

}
```

**Simple Java class**

```
@Component
public class StoreWorker {

    @Autowired
    private StoreRepository storeRepository;

    public StoreWorker() {

        System.out.println(storeRepository.findAll()); /* Error */

    }
```

**Error :**

```
Exception in thread "StoreWorker : restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.store.workers.StoreWorker]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please explain your solution with sample code as I am new to Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code in this way:

If you want to use your autowired bean in the constructor of your class, use constructor injection. This is also the most recommended way of injection.

```
@Component
public class StoreWorker {

    private final StoreRepository storeRepository;

    public StoreWorker(StoreRepository storeRepository) {
        this.storeRepository = storeRepository;
        System.out.println(storeRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

So when the `StoreWorker` gets instantiated the autowired bean `storeRepository` gets injected. Since this happens you are able to use `storeRepository` bean.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put any logic in the constructor. Constructor methods are just to initialize your instance.
Make the call to the `storeRepository` in a separate method.

```
@Component
public class StoreWorker {
    @Autowired
    private StoreRepository storeRepository;

    public void findAll() {
        System.out.println(storeRepository.findAll()); 
    }
}
```

When Spring is calling your constructor, the context is not fully initialized, and since you don't use constructor injection, `storeRepository` is not injected yet.

Constructor injection is the recommended way to inject by the Spring team. And as of Spring 4.3, you don't even need to add the `@Autowired` annotation on constructors.

```
@Component
public class StoreWorker {

    private StoreRepository storeRepository;

    //@Autowired not needed since v4.3
    public StoreWorker(StoreRepository storeRepository) {
        this.storeRepository = storeRepository;
    }

    ...
}
```

If you want to do further initialization of your bean relying on other external beans, do it in a separate method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

```
@Component
public class StoreWorker {

    private StoreRepository storeRepository;
    private List<Store> stores;

    public StoreWorker(StoreRepository storeRepository) {
        this.storeRepository = storeRepository;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeMyBean() {
        stores = storeRepository.findAll(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You should use @Autowire in the constructor level in order to use Autowire variable inside the constructor.

```
@Component
public class StoreWorker {


@Autowired
public StoreWorker(StoreRepository storeRepository) {

    System.out.println(storeRepository.findAll()); 

}
```

(or) Use  PostConstruct

[Autowiring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) happens after the construction of an object. Therefore they will not be set until after the constructor has completed.

If you need to run some initialization code, you should be able to pull the code in the constructor into a method and annotate that method with @PostConstruct.

Comment: Tried with annotations for Repository  and also with Component   still i get  System.out.println(storeRepository);  = NULL

Comment: Guys, Put a comment then downvote the answer so that if there is any flaw in my answer I can correct it. Simply downvoting the answer makes others hurt and it stops to answer other questions in stackover flow.

Comment: `@Repository` annotation is not needed when extending `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` interface

Comment: @Matt Thank you for your comment. But mentioning Repository will not harm the class still it is fine. although I have answered the question in the second part of my answer. Instead of a downvote, you can edit the answer right? It's spoiled my weekend

Comment: And what makes you think I downvoted your answer? I was just making a comment

Comment: The `@Repository` not present is not the reason why the code doesn't work as your answer imply. You should put the second part first then as it is the primary reason. Don't let that spoil your weekend ;) At least you provided an answer, which is always a good thing.

Comment: @Matt Extremely sorry. I thought after seeing your message you are the one downvoted my answer and i was really pissed off.

Comment: It's better to use construction injection, as stated in the other answers since Spring 4.3 the ```@Autowired``` annotation is not required anymore! :-)